# "You must enter a password with at least one number a lower case and a symbol"

Tags: java, function

I would like to strengthen the password requirements when a user wants to register.

I wrote the following code in the servlet Registration.java :

```
public static boolean checkpassword(password) {
    boolean hasNum = false;
    boolean hasCap = false;
    boolean hasLow = false;
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
        c = password.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            hasNum = true;
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            hasCap = true;
        } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
            hasLow = true;
        } else if (hasNum && hasCap && hasLow) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, I don't know where to put it in my servlet below:

```
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String postalcode = request.getParameter("postalcode");

        if (password == password1 && email.contains("@")) {

            try {
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/Oussama/login.db");
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps.setString(2, firstname);
                ps.setString(3, lastname);
                ps.setString(4, email);
                ps.setString(5, password);
                ps.setString(6, country);
                ps.setString(7, city);
                ps.setString(8, address);
                ps.setString(9, postalcode);

                int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                if (i > 0)
                    out.print("You are successfully registered...");

            } catch (Exception e2) {
                System.out.println(e2);
            }

            out.close();
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Passwords do not match");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to put it before and after however, I still have an error.

Do you guys know where I an put this block of code (which I believe is working) ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One obvious error would be missing type for `password` parameter here: `public static boolean checkpassword(password)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method to check the strength of the password is not complete. Write it as follows:

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
    String pattern = "^(?=.*?\\p{Upper})(?=.*?\\p{Lower})(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?\\p{Punct}).{4,}";
    return password.matches(pattern);
}
```

**Explanation:**

- At least one upper case letter `(?=.*?\\p{Upper})`
- At least one lower case letter `(?=.*?\\p{Lower})`
- At least one digit `(?=.*?[0-9])`
- At least one special character `(?=.*?\\p{Punct})`
- One each of the above makes at least 4 characters mandatory `{4,}`

Check [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn more about regex patterns.

**A quick demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] testStrs = { "Hello", "Ab1#", "Abc123", "ABC123$" };
        for (String s : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(s + " -> " + (isValidPassword(s) ? "meets the criteria" : "does not meet the criteria"));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
        String pattern = "^(?=.*?\\p{Upper})(?=.*?\\p{Lower})(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?\\p{Punct}).{4,}";
        return password.matches(pattern);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello -> does not meet the criteria
Ab1# -> meets the criteria
Abc123 -> does not meet the criteria
ABC123$ -> does not meet the criteria
```

---

Never compare strings using `==` which compares the references; not the content. You have used

```
if (password == password1)
```

which should be

```
if (password.equals(password1))
```

---

I believe `password` and `password1` pertain to the values from **Password** and **Confirm password** input fields. Use the `isValidPassword` method (mentioned above) as shown below:

```
//...
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String password1 = request.getParameter("password1");
//...

if (password.equals(password1) && isValidPassword(password) && email.contains("@")) {

    //...

}
```